# clean email list from MD5 hash

Tags: powershell, md5

I am trying to delete some mails from a list 'data.txt' where their hash figure in another list 'MD5.txt'

bellow is the script I made (it works fine but only for small files)

```
function Get-MD5{
    Param ([String]$mail)
    $md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($mail)))
    $hash = $hash.Replace('-','')
    return [String]$hash
    }

    $data = gc $dataPath
    $unsub = gc $MD5Path #ReadCount 5000 -Raw not better    
    foreach($d in $data){
        $t = Get-MD5 "$d"
        if($unsub -like "*$t*"){    
            $data | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "$d" } | Out-File -FilePath "$dataPath"
        }
    }
```

the problem I am having is that the MD5 file is too large (more than 1Gb), so even with 16 Gb of RAM, the script is not able to compare each line (mail) with millions of MD5 lines. (it makes 30  seconds for each line)

Any ideas how can I do this task faster ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a few tips but without actual files and testing now sure how much of an improvement would it be.

- Avoid using "|" as much as possible, that slows everything down
- you can use -readcount 0 to read the whole file at once, you have enough ram to handle it
- Instead of writing to file over and over, which would require you to access disk, do a memory operation, and write out at once.
- like is a slow operator, try replacing it with match, which is roughly 10x faster
- I would also take a look at compare-object, and see if you can use that the diff. E.g. A: whole list, B: list of emails to be removed, diff is what you want the final output to be (A-B)

Comment: .. I applied your tips, and I passed from 30s for each lne/mail to 5s (Still long but much better than before) thanks

Comment: can you may be post your updated code and provide some more info on the nature of files? I am wondering if sorting them first would be help... Also, you could use measure-object to do some testing to find out where exactly are the bottlenecks.